# How can i handle recurring payment in stripe for indian payments while stripe waits for 72 hours

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, recurring-billing, laravel-cashier

i have integrated stripe recurring subscription on our project. But we are facing an issue that.

As most of the users of our platform are indian and for each indian recurring payment stripe waits for 72 hours ( 3days ). for example if i have a recurring payment of 30 days then payment gets completed on 33 day. But as per our business need we need to make the recurring in 30 days only.

Can anyone suggest how can i accomplish this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since Stripe integrates with partner platform, it will wait [72 hours](https://stripe.com/docs/india-recurring-payments#effect-on-transactions) to charge the customer. If you wish to charge the customer every 30 days, you may initiate the payment request 3 days in advance.

Alternatively, you may provide 3 days waiting/grace period for recurring payment. If the payment fails afterwards, then cancel the subscription at 33th day.

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few ideas that may help you address the delay in payment processing for Indian users on your platform:

Use a payment gateway that does not have a hold policy for Indian users: you could consider using a different payment gateway that does not have a hold policy for payments from Indian users. This may help you avoid delays in payment processing.

Implement fraud prevention measures: Implementing additional fraud prevention measures, such as requiring additional verification steps or using advanced fraud detection tools, may help reduce the risk of fraudulent transactions and reduce the likelihood of payments being held for review.

Provide more information to Stripe: If you are using Stripe and are unable to switch to a different payment gateway, you could consider providing more information to Stripe to help them verify the validity of the payments.

This may include details about your business, the products or services you are selling, and the nature of the transactions being processed.

Consider using a different payment method: Depending on your business and the needs of your customers, you may want to consider offering alternative payment methods that do not have the same hold policy.

For example, you could offer the option to pay with a credit card or bank transfer, which may have a shorter hold period or no hold period at all.

Hope that helps give you some ideas